# show hide div on mouseover and mouseout

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_sidebar()
{
document.getElementById('sidebar').style.visibility="visible";
}

function hide_sidebar()
{
document.getElementById('sidebar').style.visibility="hidden";
}
</script>

<img src="images/cart.jpg" width="80px" height="30px" onMouseOver="show_sidebar()"     onMouseOut="hide_sidebar()">

<div id="sidebar">some thing</div>
```

This is my code for showing and hiding sidebar div on mouseover and mouseout. Its working but i want is when i have mouseover on image, sidebar div is shown and i want sidebar div to be shown also when mouse is over sidebar. How can u do it.

Comment: Can you wrap them in a common parent?

Comment: so put your onmouseover stuff onto the sidebar html as well?

Comment: Try putting the `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` events on your div tag.

Comment: how can i solve those problem by doing so @problemPotato

Comment: yes, but does it make a difference.. @epascarello

Comment: no it doesnot make any@epascarello

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Move the eventhandlers to a wrapper div to accomplish what you want.

```html
<div id="wrapper" onMouseOver="show_sidebar()" onMouseOut="hide_sidebar()">
  <img src="images/cart.jpg" width="80px" height="30px">
  <div id="sidebar">some thing</div>
</div>
```

Comment: onMouseOut worked for me. Code : function ClosePopUp(id) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    if (div != undefined && div != null) {
        div.style.display = "none"; 
    }
}

Answer (score 17):

If you can wrap them in a common parent it is as simple with just CSS, no JavaScript is needed.

**CSS:**

```
#sidebar {
    display: none;
}
.cart:hover #sidebar {
    display:block;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="cart">
    <img src="images/cart.jpg" width="80px" height="30px" />
    <div id="sidebar">some thing</div>
</div>
```

**Example:**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2236p/)

It can be done without wrapping, but you have to make sure that the image and div overlap so the cursor can move into the div. Wrapping it avoids that problem.

Also note, not everyone uses a mouse.

Comment: And this solution is better than the JavaScript solution...No need to use JavaScript to do something simple like this unless you are supporting really old IE7.

Comment: "Also note, not everyone uses a mouse." Yes - this won't work with touch. But nice anyway.

Answer (score 3):

use it with css, it simplier

```
 <style>
   #sidebar{
       display : none;
   }
   img:hover ~ #sidebar {
       display : block;
   }
    #sidebar:hover {
       display : block;
   }
</style>
<img src="images/cart.jpg" width="80px" height="30px" >

<div id="sidebar">some thing</div>
```

With delay :

```
<style>
#sidebar{

    opacity : 0;
}
img:hover ~ #sidebar {
    opacity : 1;
}
 #sidebar:hover {
    opacity : 1;
}
 #sidebar:not(hover) {
    animation-delay:2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:2s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
    opacity : 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This is not going to work unless the image and sidebar overlap.

Answer (score 3):

Here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/luckmattos/CV9uX/

**with Jquery**

```
$('#img').hide(); 

$('#sidebar').mouseover(function () {
      $('#img').show();      
});
$('#sidebar').mouseout(function () {
      $('#img').hide();      
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="sidebar">Show on Over</a>

<div class="img"><img src="http://www.highsnobiety.com/files/2013/05/lamborghini-egoista-concept-car-9.jpg" width="250px" id="img">
    </div>
```

Comment: You missed the problem....Code has the same exact issue the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: Confusing question, but the function to work is there, just switch elements. Harsh down vote. But thanks.

Comment: The code has the same exact problem as the OPs. Just using jQuery for showing and hiding is NOT going to fix it! Make a fiddle and try to put your image on the image. It is supposed to stay visible. In yours it will hide. That is what the OP was trying to figure out. That is why you got the downvote.

Answer (score -1):

Invisible elements don't have mouse events. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_sidebar()
{
document.getElementById('sidebar').style.opacity = 1;
}

function hide_sidebar()
{
document.getElementById('sidebar').style.opacity = 0;
}
</script>

<img src="images/cart.jpg" width="80px" height="30px" onMouseOver="show_sidebar()" onMouseOut="hide_sidebar()">
<div id="sidebar" style="opacity: 0;" onMouseOver="show_sidebar()">some thing</div>
```

Comment: And there is no mouse events on an invisible element.

Comment: Yeah that was what I was trying to say, added it to my answer.

Comment: Did you add the event listener to the sidebar?

Comment: The mouseout is still going to fire on the image so it will hide.... Race condition, will the out or over fire first?

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the best and easy method working with latest jquery version.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#div2").hide();
$("#div1").mouseover(function(){
$("#div2").fadeIn();
});
$("#div1").mouseout(function(){
$("#div2").fadeOut();
});
});

</script>

<div id="div1">Move the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</div>
<div id="div2" >div2.</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_sidebar()
{
document.getElementById('sidebar').style.display="block";
}

function hide_sidebar()
{
document.getElementById('sidebar').style.display="none";
}
</script>

<img src="images/cart.jpg" width="80px" height="30px" onMouseOver="show_sidebar()"     onMouseOut="hide_sidebar()">

<div id="sidebar">some thing</div>
```

Comment: How is that any different?