# Make a div appear on onmouseover, but remain if the mouse hovers over it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a description box appear over an element when the mouse hovers over it, and disappear when it leaves. However, simply doing

```
$("element").mouseenter(function() {
    // make box appear
}).mouseleave(function() {
    // make box disappear
});
```

Will make the box disappear if the mouse is hovering over the box itself. How do I keep it on the screen as long as the mouse is either on the target element or on the box that appears beside it?

Comment: $("#element, #appearing_div").mouseleave(function() {});

Comment: You can add the `event` parameter to the callback function and check the target property to see the current hovered element (`mouseenter(function(e) { console.log(e.target)})`)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327233/show-hide-div-on-mouseover-and-mouseout have you done this ..??

Comment: Is that what you want https://jsfiddle.net/u38877th/1/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need javascript for this!

```css
#square {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
#parent {
  height 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#parent:hover #square {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="square">:-)</div>
</div>
^^^^^^Hover Above^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#element").on({
mouseenter: function () {
    $("#box").fadeIn();
},
mouseleave: function () {
    var $target = $("#box");


    var timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $target.stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    }, 200);
    $target.data('hoverTimer', timer);
}
});
```

Try this.

Answer (score -1):

This should do it,

```
 stay= false
  $(element).hover(function(){
      console.log('mouseover');
      $(box).show();
      $(box).hover(function(){
         stay=true;
       }, 
       function(){
           exitHover();
           console.log('mouseout if box');
        });
  },
  function(){
     exitHover();
     console.log('mouseout');
  });
  function exitHover(){
      if(stay) return;
      //hide box
  }
```

Ohh boy, completely missed your other part of the question, updated.