# Bootstrap 5 how to show/hide button on a card with css

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap-cards

I have a row of cards and when I mouse over one of the cards, I want a "Shop Now" button to appear on the card.  Is there a way to do it with just CSS?

This is the part of the card with the button:

```
<div class="card-text">
  <button type="button" id="btnShopNow" class="btn btn-primary">Shop Now</button>
</div>
```

Here is what I have for the css so far:

```
.btnShopNow .card {
    display:none;
}

.card:hover {
  transform:scale(1.1);
  background-color:#f8f9fa; 
  /* need to figure out how to do something like #btnShopNow display:block; */
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327233/show-hide-div-on-mouseover-and-mouseout

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  This isn't going to work for me, however, because the button would have to be in the div that gets hidden which would be on a small part of the larger card.  So, they would have to mouse over a hidden part of the card which is unlikely to happen consistently.  If I made the div big and on the entire card, I believe the card itself would be hidden.